# Fast and Small C++ https proxy

Tags: proxy, https

I'm looking for a small, fast, and reliable https proxy that I can extend to do the following:

1. Look for https handshake requests.
2. Run a regular expression against the host name being requested.
3. If the expression matches the host name then don't send the request on but respond with a 302 redirect to a different site.

So, I guess I have the following questions about this:

1. Is this possible?  (I'm pretty sure the handshake request is not encrypted, I know I can do some pattern matching, the real question is...would I be able to send a fake 302 redirect to the client without it complaining about not having completed the handshake?)
2. If it is possible, is there a linux app out there that does some or all of this? (I found this: http://www.kubat.nl/pages/microproxy)  I was considering trying to build the remaining features into it but didn't want to try that if something else already does it.
3. Do you have suggestions for other C++ Linux proxies I might be able to build this into?

Thanks in advance for your feedback.

EV

Comment: BTW, welcome to Unix SE.  How about editing [your profile](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/17079) and changing your Display Name to something better than user548971?

Comment: Are you looking for a standalone program, or does it have to be a C++ library? If you want a library, you should ask on [so], a Stack Exchange site for programmers; [unix.se] is for users and administrators. Don't repost; if you specifically need a C++ library, a moderator can migrate this question to [so].

Comment: It can really be either.  I just need to it to run on linux and be extensible.  Microproxy might actually be the ticket.  Squid is much to big for my application.  I had thought about posting at Stack Overflow.  What I need is rather specialized.  I would say to leave the question here for now.  If I have a more pointed programming question I will post it there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> 3: Do you have suggestions for other C++ Linux proxies I might be able
>   to build this into?

[squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) is a fast open source proxy that you can extend to your heart's content

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible either, unless by "URL" you mean "hostname".  The [Server Name Indication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4366#section-3.1) extension allows the client to indicate the hostname it's trying to connect to.  Many browsers now [support SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication#Support).  But the full URL isn't transmitted until after the handshake is complete.

So you can tell the difference between `https://www.example.com/` and `https://other.example.com/`, but not between `https://www.example.com/one` and `https://www.example.com/another`.

Maybe if you explained exactly why you think you need to do this, somebody could come up with a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  That's good to know.  For some reason I thought the handshake request included the url not just the domain/host name.  The question is really the same.  I'm good with just seeing the domain.